# Kafka Connect S3 Sink Connector Partitioning large topics by id field

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

We've been working on adding Kafka Connect to our data platform for the last few weeks and think it would be a useful way of extracting data from Kafka into an S3 datalake. We've played around with FieldPartitioner and the TimeBasePartitioner and seen some pretty decent results.

We also have the need to partition by user id - but having tried using the FieldPartitioner on a user id field the connector is extremely slow - especially compared to partitioning by date etc. I understand that partitioning by an id will create a lot of output partitions and thus won't be as fast - which is fine but it needs to be able to keep up with producers.

So far we've tried increasing memory and heap - but we don't usually see any memory issues unless we bump the flush.size to a large number. We've also tried small flush sizes, very small and large rotate.schedule.interval.ms configurations. We've also looked at networking, but that seems to be fine - using other partitioners the network keeps up fine.

Before potentially wasting a lot of time on this has anyone attempted or succeeded in partitioning by an id field, especially on larger topics, using the S3 Sink Connector? Or has anyone got any suggestions in terms of configuration or setup that might be a good place to look?

Comment: How many tasks and workers do you have? I'm assuming the problem is that every task is processing a high cardinality of ids (as compared to only a few partitions or a sequentially increasing date within the date partition window), and not reaching the flush size for any given ID partition very quickly

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, thanks for the comment. On a single topic we have three partitions and I have set max.tasks to 3. We also have 3 connect workers in distributed mode. I suspected the same with the flush size and have tried setting flush size to 1, but still see issues with throughput.

Comment: So, which part is actually slow? Uploading the files or the consuming? In other words, are you monitoring the consumer lag? From what I've seen from connectors with really large producer volumes and large flush sizes is that connect batches data for a while, then commits thousands of offsets, but all the data seems to be fine in S3; it's just slow to get there sometimes

Comment: What I mean by slow is the consumers never seem to have the ability to keep up with the producers. The consumers struggle to get through the data currently in the topic and the lag grows slowly over time. In contrast with the same topic and using the TimeBasedPartitioner we observe the lag reducing steadily over the course of a couple hours. What do you mean its slow to get there sometimes? Appreciate the comments!

Comment: The data is slow to upload to S3. But the consumer is indeed working. The offsets only get commited (therefore the lag only reduces) once the files are actually uploaded. This is a byproduct of having exactly once delivery to S3

Comment: Hi, do you know how can i partitioning my data with key? the value of partition.field.name should be set to which value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to Kafka's connector, but I will at least try to help.

I am not aware if you can configure the connector to kafka topic's partition level; I am assuming there's some way to do that here.

One possible way to do this would be **focused on the step where your clients produce to the Kafka brokers**. My suggestion is to implement your own `Partitioner`, in order to have a "further" control of where you want to send the data on kafka's side.

This is an example/simplification of your custom partitioner. For example, the `key` your producers send has this format: `id_name_date`. This custom partitioner tries to extract the first element (`id`) and then chooses the desired partition.

```
public class IdPartitioner implements Partitioner 
{       
   @Override
   public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] kb, 
                        Object v, byte[] vb, Cluster cl) 
   {
       try 
       {
         String pKey= (String) key;
         int id = Integer.parseInt(pKey.substring(0,pKey.indexOf("_")));
        
          /* getPartitionForId would decide which partition number corresponds
           for the received ID.You could also implement the logic directly here.*/

         return getPartitionForId(id);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {return 0;}
   }

   @Override
   public void close() 
   {
     //maybe some work here if needed
   }
}
```

Even if you'll may need some more tunning on `KafkaConnect` side, I believe this option may be helpful. Assuming you have a topic with 5 partitions, and that  `getPartitionForId` just checks the first number of the ID in order to decide the partition (*for simplification purposes, min Id is 100 and max Id is 599*).

So if the received key is, f.e: `123_tempdata_20201203`, the partition method would return `0`, that is, the 1st partition.

*(The image shows P1 instead of P0 because i believe the example looks more natural this way, but be aware that the 1st partition is in fact defined as `partition 0` . Ok to be honest I forgot about P0 while painting this and didn't save the template, so I had to search for an excuse, like: looks more natural).*

[image: simplification of broker-side partitioning]

**Basically this would be a *pre-adjustment*, or *acommodation*, before the S3 upload.**

I am aware maybe this isn't the ideal answer, as I don't know the exact specifications of your system. ***My guess is that there's some possibility to directly point topic partitions to s3 locations**.*

If there's no possibility to do so, at least I hope this could give you some further ideas. Cheers!

Comment: The default S3 partitioner uses TopicPartitions

Comment: Hey @aran! Appreciate the detailed post and will look into this as a possibility.